# Qt: Is the QBuffer thread safe in this code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The code is given as:

```
class USBCamCaptureThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

void run() {
    while (!threadQuit){
        if (imageReaded){
            buffer->reset();
            Request = http->get (url->path(),buffer););
        }
        MG::SLEEP::msleep(250);
    }
 }

public:
USBCamCaptureThread(){
    QFile file("setting_files/cameraIP.txt");
    QString line = "192.168.1.5:80"; //default value
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in(&file);
        line = in.readLine();
    } 
    file.close();
    url = new QUrl(line);
    http = new QHttp(this);
    buffer = new QBuffer(&bytes);
    threadQuit = false;
    imageReaded = true;
}

~USBCamCaptureThread(){
}

public slots:
void Finished(int requestId, bool error){
        QImage localImage;
        localImage.loadFromData(bytes);

        QImg = localImage;
        bytes.clear();

        emit signalUSBImageRead();
}
```

Note that the *Finished()* is in the main thread, and the *run()* is in a worker thread.
May question is by reading/writing to the *bytes* and *buffer* in separate threads, will it cause thread related issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Finished` is called while `run` is active, then yes, you have a problem.  Sharing data between two threads that run in a pipeline (serially) isn't necessarily a problem.  Accessing non-threadsafe, shared data between two threads at the same time is always a problem.  I haven't used Qt in many years so `QBuffer` or `QImage::loadFromData` may offer thread safety guarantees of their own as well.

Comment: they don't, just that 2 separate instances don't share data that would need synchronizing

Comment: @ratchetfreak, but I think in this example, buffer and bytes are internally the same? since buffer = new QBuffer (&bytes)